# Toggle CSS Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, toggleclass

I'm trying to show this CSS on the first click and remove it on the next but toggleClass doesnt seem to work and neither does my code below. All I can get is the CSS to show and it never gets removed. This is for use on Safari on iOS. Thanks for the help!

```
                var menu_enabled = false;

                $('#nav a').click(function () {
                    if (menu_enabled == true) {
                        $(this).removeClass('sf-js-enabled');
                        var menu_enabled = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        var menu_enabled = true;
                        $(this).addClass('sf-js-enabled');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You don't need to preface the variable `menu_enabled` with `var` inside the `if`/`else`, you've already declared it. Can you reproduce the problem with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Answer (score 3):

You should checkout **[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**, looks like it's exactly what you're wanting.

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('sf-js-enabled');
});
```

Comment: I realise that he didn't explain precisely what, if anything, happens but he did explicitly state that `toggleClass()` isn't working. (I agree that it *should*, but that assertion suggests that he's got a problem elsewhere in his code, rather than the possibility he's missing a particular jQuery method).

Comment: Tried toggleClass already, like I said above, doesn't remove the class on what I'm using, iPad.

Comment: ok, then that's your question, cross browser issues with Safari on iOS

Comment: @Jason: how do you know that?

Comment: @duality_ i've tried to make it work. for some reason, ios can't handle it. chalk it up to another apple bug

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the .className attribute?

```
var menu_enabled = false;

$('#nav a').click(function () {
 if (menu_enabled == true) {
  $(this).className = "";
  menu_enabled = false;
 }else 
 {
  menu_enabled = true;
  $(this).className = 'sf-js-enabled';
 }
});
```

Comment: .className works on iOS, Safari (I just tested it on my iPhone). I believe the issue is with jQuery. Have you considered setting an id to the anchor and then targeting it through document.getElementById and making the onclick from the anchor call a javascript function? This may seem like over-engineering, but if libraries are not available to use then you will have to roll your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I cant use that onclick method but I appreciate the good idea.

Comment: Have you considered using a `<button>` instead of an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish overall, but addClass and removeClass should work just fine. I would add an ID or class to the element that you want to have the click attached to but that's just a personal preference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#element').click(function(){
        if($('#element').hasClass('sf-js-enabled')){
            $('#element').removeClass();
        }
        else{
            $('#element').addClass('sf-is-enabled');
        }
    });
});
```